# If $x$ and $y$ are real and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, compute the maximum value of $(x+y)^2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

If $x$ and $y$ are real and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, compute the maximum value of $(x+y)^2.$

---

Should I manipulate the equation?  I'm stuck on this problem.  Answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend writing $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ and using trig identities.

Comment: @DavidHill  I haven't learned trig yet, so a solution without trig would be great.

Comment: Note that $(x+y)^2=1+2xy$ and $2xy\leq x^2+y^2=1$ with equality when $x=y=\frac 12$.

Comment: Just draw a picture? Unit circle, parallel lines $x+y=C$...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trig-free solution: If $x^2+y^2=1$ then
$$
(x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 2(x^2+y^2)=2
$$
so the largest value of $(x+y)^2$ is $2$, attained when $x=y$.

Comment: Very nice! $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 4):

One way: since $x^2+y^2=1$ you can write $x=\cos(\theta)$, $y=\sin(\theta)$ for $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$. Then
$$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy=1+2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$$
Can you see what's the maximum value of this new function?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I manipulate the equation?

Yes! Try this:
$$
(x + y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = 1 + 2xy.
$$

So now what you really have to do is maximize $xy$, given that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
**Hint:** write $x = \sin \theta$, $y = \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$(x\times 1+y\times 1 )^2 \leq (x^2+y^2)(1^2+1^2), x^2+y^2=1$$

$$ (x+y)^2 \leq (1)(2)$$

$$-\sqrt{2} \leq x+y \leq \sqrt{2} $$